# Java Inheritance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a class A

```
public class A{

   public void doWork(){
              ..............
              .............
   }

}
```

Now a public class B extends A

```
public class B extends A{

   @override
   public void doWork(){
          ............
          ............
   }

}
```

Now Public class C create a object of B into it and pass it to a method of class D

```
import xxx.xxx.B;
import xxx.xxx.D;

public class C{
     B b= new B();
     D d = new D();

     d.method(b);
}
```

now class D takes a argument of type A into its method and operate on it.

```
public class D{

   public void method(A a){
      ..........
      ..........
   }

}
```

Actually It is allowed, but I cannot understand why it is allowed ?
method() in class D should take an object of type A.
Please help me out ?

Comment: Child of a class can be referred by its parent name. It same as some people use father's name in their name. Keeping it simple :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B` is an extension of `A`. For example, take a class `Animal`, and a class `Dog extends Animal`. `Dog` is still an `Animal`. Same goes for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `extends` like that, you're saying that class `B` "is a" class `A`, just a more *specialized* version of it. You might have `Shape`, for instance, and then `Circle extends Shape`. `Circle` **is a** `Shape`, just a specialization of it. That's why it's called subclassing: You're making a more specific class that is (usually) a subset of the general class.

"Is a" is probably *the* most fundamental relationship in inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

## [Covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

> If Cat is subtype of Animal, then an expression of type Cat can be used whenever an expression of type Animal could

Your `B is extends  A`. So, **`B` Also have the properties of `A`**

You are expecting a A ..So you are satisfied by receiving `B` which have the properties of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the concept of polymorphism, a key part of Object Oriented programming. an instance of B extends from A, and thus can be polymorphically treated as an instance of A.

NOTE: The reverse is not true, ie. an instance of A cannot be treated as an instance of B

Answer (score 0):

The `method` in D may take any class that subclasses A.

Beware of type safety. Currently, in your `method` in D, all methods you call on the parameter will execute A's implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Method() in class D can take an object of type A or a subtype of A. In this case B extends A, so it works perfectly. Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html